# Environment in Rcpp

Tags: r, hash, hashtable, environment, rcpp

I'm dealing with an optimisation problem that involves the use of a likelihood function (`lik`) and its gradient (`grad`). Both functions are coded using `Rcpp` library and are fed to the `optim(...,method="BFGS")` optimisation function in R.

During the computation of the likelihood, many variables are created, and there will also be useful for the future computation of the gradient. In order to avoid recomputing those variables each time that a gradient evaluation is needed, I came up with the idea of creating an Environment (`env`) that `lik` uses to "communicate" with `grad`. In other words, each time that `lik` is evaluated, it stores into the environment `env` the needed variables

```
likelihoodscript<-
using Rcpp::Environment; 
Environment e(env);
// likelihood function is computed
//var1 to varK are created
//they can be MatrixXd, SparseMatrix, double, etc.
e.assign("namevar1",var1);
e.assign("namevar2",var2);
...
e.assign("namevarK",varK);
return wrap(likvalue);
```

Then, when a `grad` evaluation is needed, I search the needed variables in the environment from the `grad` function:

```
gradientscript<-
using Rcpp::Environment; 
Environment e(env);
//var1 to varK are recovered from the environment
SEXP input_var1 = e.get("var1");
int var1 = as<int>(var1);
SEXP input_var2= e.get("var2");
MatrixXd var2 = as<MatrixXd>(var2);
...
SEXP input_varK = e.get("varK");
double varK = as<double>(varK);
// gradient function is computed
return wrap(gradvector);
```

In theory, if I start the optimisation problem with the same initial set of parameters I should arrive to the same results every and each time (there is no random operation inside `lik`, `grad` or `optim()`), BUT it happens that the results are  sometimes different. Let say that, if I repeat the optimisation with exactly the same parameters 20 times, 15 times I have the good results, but 5 of them I have something different (or very different). I searched for a "pattern" in these errors, but they look to be completely random.

To my knowledge, that can be due to a wrong key-value identification in the hash table of the environment, hence I tried using the `hash` package in R. Some improvements (maybe 18 times the good results, instead of 15), but not yet an exact solution to the problem.

If some one has an idea of where the problem can come from, please answer.
Thank you very much.

P.D. I tried the same thing, but using a `list` instead of a `Environment`: same problem, or even worst.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a concrete example from your side it's hard to tell what the problem is. Here is what I figured out could be your code. Maybe this helps you, or it helps you to point out where you differ from my example.
My code works and all different runs of optim with `cpp` functions give the same result.

```
library(inline)

#Rosenbrock Banana function as in optim examples
#it stores two values in the provided environment
fun_str='using Rcpp::Environment; 
Environment e(env);
NumericVector xx(x);
double a=(xx[1] - xx[0] * xx[0]);
double b=(1.0 - xx[0]);
e.assign("a",a);
e.assign("b",b);
return(wrap(100.0 * pow(a,2.0) + pow(b,2.0)));'

#corresponding gradient
#it accesses the two variables that we have stored above
grad_str='using Rcpp::Environment; 
Environment e(env);
double a=e["a"];
double b=e["b"];
NumericVector xx(x);
NumericVector res(2);
res[0]= -400.0 * xx[0] * a - 2.0 * b;
res[1]=200.0*a;
return(wrap(res));'

#define rcpp functions
fun_cpp=cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric",env = "environment"),
                    fun_str,
                    plugin = "Rcpp")
grad_cpp=cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric",env = "environment"),
                     grad_str,
                     plugin = "Rcpp")

res_vec=list()

#loop through 100 runs of the same BFGS optimization and store results
for (i in 1:100) {
  container_env=new.env()
  res_vec[[length(res_vec)+1]]=optim(par=c(-1.2,1),fn=fun_cpp,gr=grad_cpp,method="BFGS",env=container_env)
}

#compare all results
sum_var=0
for (i in 2:length(res_vec)) sum_var=sum_var+all.equal(res_vec[[i]],res_vec[[i-1]])
sum_var
#99
```

So as you see they all give the same result.
Also, the results coincide with the result from the R only code given in the `optim` examples section.

Comment: Thank you very much cryo111!! I fixed the problem. 
At the end, there was a problem affecting the evaluations of the gradient function. Nothing related to environments, hashes or whatever.
Anyway, thank you for your code. It has been useful to prove that I was on the right path, and that the problem should have been searched elsewhere. 

I'm going to report the problem of the gradient evaluations. I'm checking now more carefully, but it seems to be a bug.